# __has_feature(modules) is only sometimes yes

Tags: ios, objective-c, module, c-preprocessor

I have a project that has `Enable Modules (C and Objective-C)` set to `Yes`. I do not have a file called Ararar.h, so the following should now give me build failures:

```
#if __has_feature(modules)
#import "Ararar.h"
#endif
```

The funny thing is that in some of my .h files it gives a build error, and in others it doesn't. Can you help me figure out why it in some .h files doesn't cause a compile error?

What I've found so far is that the lack of compilation error only comes in header files that are only imported from .m files. Header files that are imported from .h files make this correctly into a build error.

Comment: Well, header files are not built. Only `*.m` files are built. Headers are compiled only when included (recursively) from an `*.m` file.

Comment: Did you clean your project, by the way? The compiler uses a cache when processing module headers.